# I am trying to make a simple toggle button in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a simple toggle button in javascript. However, the button will only turn "OFF" and will not turn back "ON"

```
<html><head></head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggle(button)
{
  if(document.getElementById("1").value=="OFF"){
   document.getElementById("1").value="ON";}

  if(document.getElementById("1").value=="ON"){
   document.getElementById("1").value="OFF";}
}
</script>
<body>
<form action="">
<input type="button" id="1" value="ON" style="color:blue"
       onclick="toggle(this);">
</form></body></html>
```

I am running:HP Netbook : Ubuntu Linux 10.04 : Firefox for Ubuntu 1.0.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Both of your `if` statements are getting executed one after each other, as you change the value and then immediately read it again and change it back:

```
function toggle(button)
{
  if(document.getElementById("1").value=="OFF"){
   document.getElementById("1").value="ON";}

  else if(document.getElementById("1").value=="ON"){
   document.getElementById("1").value="OFF";}
}
```

Adding the `else` in there should stop this happening.

Comment: Also, if you know that the value can only be "ON" or "OFF", you can omit the second `if` completely and simply use `else`.

Answer (score 20):

Why are you passing the button if you're going to look it up?

Also, since you know the possible values, you only need to check if it's OFF, otherwise, you know it's ON.

```
// Toggles the passed button from OFF to ON and vice-versa.
function toggle(button) {
  if (button.value == "OFF") {
    button.value = "ON";
  } else {
    button.value = "OFF";
  }
}
```

If you wanna get fancy and save a couple of bytes you can use the ternary operator:

```
function toggle(b){b.value=(b.value=="ON")?"OFF":"ON";}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another method to do this is:

```
var button = document.querySelector("button");
var body = document.querySelector("body");
var isOrange = true;

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
if(isOrange) {
    body.style.background = "orange";
}else {
    body.style.background = "none";
}
isOrange = !isOrange;
});
```

In the `JavaScript` file.

/*****

NOTE!
Another way is applying a class to the element that we want to change.

The `CSS` file must have the class with the format we want:

```
.orange {
background: orange;
}
```

By last in our `js` file we only need to make the application of the class:

```
var button = document.querySelector("button");
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.body.classList.toggle("orange");
});
```

*Regards :)*

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a switch?

```
function toggle(button) 
{
     switch(button.value)
     {
          case "ON":
               button.value = "OFF";
               break;
          case "OFF":
               button.value = "ON";
               break;
     }
}
```

Comment: A switch for a boolean value is kind of overkill.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function toggle(button)
            {
              if(document.getElementById("1").value=="OFF")
              {
               document.getElementById("1").value="ON";
              }
              else
              {
                document.getElementById("1").value="OFF";
              }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="">
            <input type="button" id="1" value="ON" style="color:blue" onclick="toggle(this);">
        </form>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: always put script in head tag because your scripts get loaded first when your page is load

Answer (score -1):

This will resolve your issue.

```
let isOn = true;
function toggle(button) {
  isOn = !isOn;
  if (isOn) {
    document.getElementById("1").value = "ON";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("1").value = "OFF";
  }
}
```