# Create toggle element without ::before and ::after

Tags: javascript, html, css

**How can I create a toggle element without using pseduo ::before and ::after?**

I want to create a toggle on an html page but without using the pseudo **::before** and **::after**.

I am currently using the method from w3Schools given here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp

However, I don't want any ::before or ::after psuedo classes. I just want classes by alone, if possible. I tried rewriting my own class for this but didn't seem to work as intended.

```
/* The switch - the box around the slider */
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

/* Hide default HTML checkbox */
.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

/* The slider */
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

I tried making a `sliderbefore` element myself without the psudeo and it didn't seem to work. (it was missing the small circle inside the toggle)

```
.sliderbefore {
          border-radius: 34px;
          position: absolute;
          cursor: pointer;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          right: 0;
          bottom: 0;
          background-color: #ccc;
          transition: .4s;
          box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
        }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Updated the question. - How can I create a toggle element without using pseduo ::before and ::after?

Comment: Repeating the question is not clarifying anything really. You can use spans or whatever to create the element.

Comment: I did attempt to code this myself. Its in the post below at the bottom. Look at the `sliderbefore` class. That was in the original post as well. Did you see that part??

Comment: @PythonKiddieScripterX I mean, you could try using JS classToggle (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_class.asp) but I don't know why you would want to go that route over just using the pseudo-classes unless you have something significantly more complicated planned for this.

Comment: @AStombaugh - I want to create a toggle without using psuedo ::before and ::after. If that isn't possible, let me know. I am just keeping the question more towards can I make a toggle without using psuedo ::before and ::after. If that isn't possible, that is totally cool. Its ONLY about this question, no other ulterior motives so to speak. Using JS `classToggle` only can turn off and on a class. It can't deal with psuedo classes because psuedo classes are not part of the dom. Its a different topic but I wanted to mention it as I don't think it may help me here, if that makes sense.

Comment: @PythonKiddieScripterX Yes, see the link I posted and the example they provide using JS.

Comment: @AStombaugh I already read that before I posted this question. I updated my last comment but I will place it down here, just incase there was a delay.   Using JS classToggle only can turn off and on a class. It can't deal with psuedo classes because psuedo classes are not part of the dom. Its a different topic but I wanted to mention it as I don't think it may help me here, if that makes sense.

Comment: @AStombaugh after re-reading your post I think there is a confustion here. I LITEREALLY want to create a toggle. I don't need to toggle between classes. I am LITTERALLY trying to create a simple toggle button on a script. I think I found a stackoverflow that answers my question but I am still testing it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047755/i-am-trying-to-make-a-simple-toggle-button-in-javascript If it does answer my question I will delete this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `classList.toggle`:

```js
    const a= document.getElementsByClassName('a');
    const b= document.getElementsByClassName('b');

    function changeColor(){ 
        a[0].classList.toggle("d");
        b[0].classList.toggle("e");

    }
```

```css
    .a{
        position: absolute;
        border:1px solid red;
        width: 500px;
        height:300px;
        background:green;
    }

.b {
   left:51px;
    position: absolute;
    top:2px;
    float: right;
        border-radius:50%;
        width: 35px;
        height:35px;
        background: white;
        transition: all 0.1s;
}
.c {

    position: absolute;
    top:40px;
    left:130px;
        border-radius:20px;
        width: 90px;
        height:40px;
        background: #ced0d4;
}
.d{
background: blue;
}
.e{
    left:4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
    <div class="c" onclick="changeColor()">
        <div class="b"></div>   
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know how you pulled of the css to make this work. The `classList` already made sense to me but didn't seem possible because they had psuedo classes for the before and after. However your classes DONT have psuedo classes which makes your perfect!

Comment: I am going to give you the answer. Altough I answered my own question, your answer is more direct as to who I can create the toggle without the pseduo before and after. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create a toggle element by using javascript and html only instead of psuedo :before and :after

```
<html><head></head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggle(button) {
  if (button.value == "OFF") {
    button.value = "ON";
  } else {
    button.value = "OFF";
  }
}
</script>
<body>
<form action="">
<input type="button" id="1" value="ON" style="color:blue"
       onclick="toggle(this);">
</form></body></html>
```

The element is an `input` which has a Value of ON.
The Toggle function will switch the toggler on and off when clicked.